# signing cocoa app for distribution

Tags: macos, code-signing, osx-gatekeeper

I am trying to get xcode to sign my app using my distribution certificate, in such a way that the app verifies correctly using both the `spctl` and `codesign` verify command lines. This is an app that will be distributed by download, not via the Mac OS Store.

I have an Apple Developer Program OSX distribution certificate. I am just a team member, not an admin in our Apple Developer Program team, but my admin made the certificate, and sent it to me.

Here is the cert in the developer program web site:

[image]

Here is the cert installed on my machine in Keychain Access:

[image]

I have created a cocoa app in xcode using File > New > Project > Cocoa. The project is called Fred so it builds Fred.app. I have not modified the code/resources for the project so it just brings up a sample window and sample menu bar.

Here is my app identity/signing:

[image]

Here are the signing settings:

[image]

Here is the "scheme":

[image]

As you can see, I have Mac Distribution chosen in the Code Sign Identity. When I do that, it gives me the error you can see in identity/signing screenshot:

> Fred has conflicting provisioning settings. Fred is automatically
>   signed for development, but a conflicting code signing identity 3rd
>   Party Mac Developer Application has been manually specified. Set the
>   code signing identity value to "Mac Developer" in the build settings
>   editor, or switch to manual signing in the project editor.

If I do choose "Mac Developer" as my Code Signing Identity, the build completes successfully. But it seems like I want to choose Mac Distribution, because I am signing for distribution, right?

In any event, when I do choose "Mac Developer" and build the app, I then use the following command lines:

```
Michael.Katz:~/Desktop$ codesign --verify --deep --strict --verbose=2 Fred.app
Fred.app: valid on disk
Fred.app: satisfies its Designated Requirement
```

but:

```
Michael.Katz:~/Desktop$ spctl --verbose -a -t exec -vv "Fred.app"
Fred.app: rejected
```

I don't know how to tell why I'm getting that "rejected", but I do believe that it means that when the app is downloaded it won't be recognized as having a valid 3rd party developer signature (and the user will have to bypass Gategeeker to get it to run).

What am I doing wrong here?

(Note that I have also included an image of my build "scheme" above. One basic question I have is that it's not clear to me if using the scheme is the only way to tell xcode to make a release build. I was thinking that the reason it wouldn't accept "Mac Distribution" as my Code Signing Identity was because I didn't have the app set to build for distribution properly.)

Comment: Try doing Xcode > Product > Archive and see if the app is signed with proper certificate then. You will want `Mac App  Distribution` for releases; `Mac Developer` is only for development/debug versions.

Comment: @I'L'I, when you say "you will want," yes that's what I assumed. But can you tell why it's giving me the error shown above when I choose "Mac Distribution?"

Comment: Somewhere in your settings you must have set it to use the other certificate "3rd Party Mac Developer Application". Above the "Targets" where it says "Project" check and see if the project file is using it.

Comment: Right, in the picture above I have set "Mac Distribution" at both the target and project levels, and I'm getting the error shown above. This is what my post is about.

Comment: Yes, I know what the post is about, I'm trying to help you — or was...

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to be rude. I was just confused because I didn't know if it was clear that what you described was what I had already done.